# ipython notebooks stop working after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-15.04

Today I recently upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 15.04. After the upgrade I see that ipython notebooks no longer work.

I am using version 4.0.0 of ipython:

```
jim@main:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

When I try to import zmq I get this error:

```
In [1]: import zmq
...
ImportError: libzmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I use ldconfig -v:

```
jim@main:~$ sudo ldconfig  -v | grep libzmq

libzmq.so.3 -> libzmq.so.3.1.0
libzmq.so.1 -> libzmq.so.1.0.1
```

I understand that I can only install one of libzmq and libzmq3. It seems I do not have the correct shared library. There is no libzmq4 package to install.

I don't really want to compile zeromq from source. Can you tell me how to install libzmq.so.4 or change ipython to a version that works with the zmq version I have.

How does this work on other people's computers? What version of ipython am I supposed to have for Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: You may want to add how you installed `ipython`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really want to compile zeromq from source.

I put on my big-boy pants and installed zeromq from source. Now it works fine.

For other people searching for the same answer, I obtained the source from here:

http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software

The current stable release of 4.1.3 creates the so file libzmq.so.5, which is too new. I had to use the retired version of 4.0.7 to get libzmq.so.4. then I could import the zmq package.

IPython notebook didn't work then though; I had to install the latest version of tornado (4.2.1). I had to remove Ubuntu's tornado package, which is 3.2.